# ADB | How do I Authorise Amazon FireTV Stick via. USB? - to run shell script on boot

Tags: android, linux, adb, amazon-fire-tv

Goal: Follow this [tutorial](https://www.aftvnews.com/how-to-automatically-run-shell-script-files-at-boot-on-a-rooted-amazon-fire-tv-or-fire-tv-stick/#delete), to run a shell script on boot.

Despite following the tutorial and trying various solutions, I am still unable to authorise the ADB connection. I'd greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Linux:

```bash
(base) me@laptop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

```bash
(base) danielbell@laptop:~$ curl ifconfig.me
109.144.211.17
```

FireTV Stick is in Developer Mode and I've both turned `OFF` and `ON` and restarted several times:

- ADB Debugging
- Apps from Unknown Sources

In 'My Fire TV' -> 'Network':

- 'IP Address:' `100.120.226.156`
- 'DNS:' `192.168.22.22`

```bash
(base) me@laptop:~$ adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 28.0.2-debian
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb

(base) me@laptop:~$ adb kill-server
(base) me@laptop:~$ adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully

(base) me@laptop:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached
G070L81693920FDB    unauthorized

(base) me@laptop:~$ adb connect 100.120.226.156
missing port in specification: tcp:100.120.226.156
(base) me@laptop:~$ adb connect 100.120.226.156:5555
failed to connect to '100.120.226.156:5555': Connection timed out

(base) me@laptop:~$ adb connect 192.168.22.22
missing port in specification: tcp:192.168.22.22
(base) me@laptop:~$ adb connect 192.168.22.22:5555
failed to connect to '192.168.22.22:5555': Connection timed out
```

Comment: What is the IP address you your Linux? If Linux and the FireTV are connected via WiFi make sure connection between Wifi clients is allowed in the used Wifi router.

Comment: You should mention you can't connect, the title is misleading

Comment: Thanks guys, updates attached to post

Comment: Have you tried pinging device Ip address? Your devices might not be on same network or your router may block connections to the target device.